# hive graph with anomalous data point

Tags: javascript, d3.js

The short array of json data below is the dataset this question is based on. Notice that `pink` only appears in the imports array and isn't the value for a "name" key. Due to this fact, I get this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined
```

when trying to create a hive plot based on [this demo](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/hive/)  by d3's creator

```
var dataset = [
{"name":"red","imports":["blue, green"]},
{"name":"blue","imports":["yellow"]},
{"name":"green","imports":["blue", "pink"]},
{"name":"yellow","imports":["red"]}
];
```

Question: is there a way to create a hive graph with anomalous data points like above, or, if not, what is another type of graph to use?

jsfiddle: [jsfiddle (doesn't work)](http://jsfiddle.net/mjmitche/Qh9X5/4354/)

Code

```
var width = 960,
    height = 850,
    innerRadius = 40,
    outerRadius = 640,
    majorAngle = 2 * Math.PI / 3,
    minorAngle = 1 * Math.PI / 12;

var angle = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(["source", "source-target", "target-source", "target"])
    .range([0, majorAngle - minorAngle, majorAngle + minorAngle, 2 * majorAngle]);

var radius = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([innerRadius, outerRadius]);

var color = d3.scale.category10();

var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + outerRadius * .20 + "," + outerRadius * .57 + ")");

// Load the data and display the plot!
d3.json("./fl.json", function(nodes) {
// d3.json("./flare-imports.json", function(nodes) {
  console.log(nodes, "nodes");
  var nodesByName = {},
      links = [],
      formatNumber = d3.format(",d"),
      defaultInfo;

  // Construct an index by node name.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.connectors = [];
    d.packageName = d.name.split(".")[1];
    nodesByName[d.name] = d;
    // console.log(d, nodesByName, "in nodes.forEach line 72, making connectors and packageName");
  });

  // Convert the import lists into links with sources and targets.
  nodes.forEach(function(source) {
    // console.log(source, "source?");
    source.imports.forEach(function(targetName) {
      var target = nodesByName[targetName];
      // console.log(target, nodesByName, targetName, "looking for target");
      if (!source.source) source.connectors.push(source.source = {node: source, degree: 0});
      if (!target.target) target.connectors.push(target.target = {node: target, degree: 0});
      links.push({source: source.source, target: target.target});

    });

  });

  // Determine the type of each node, based on incoming and outgoing links.
  nodes.forEach(function(node) {
    if (node.source && node.target) {
      node.type = node.source.type = "target-source";
      node.target.type = "source-target";
    } else if (node.source) {
      node.type = node.source.type = "source";
    } else if (node.target) {
      node.type = node.target.type = "target";
    } else {
      node.connectors = [{node: node}];
      node.type = "source";
    }
    // console.log(node, "checking node type");
  });

  // Initialize the info display.
  var info = d3.select("#info")
      .text(defaultInfo = "Showing " + formatNumber(links.length) + " dependencies among " + formatNumber(nodes.length) + " classes.");

  // Normally, Hive Plots sort nodes by degree along each axis. However, since
  // this example visualizes a package hierarchy, we get more interesting
  // results if we group nodes by package. We don't need to sort explicitly
  // because the data file is already sorted by class name.

  // Nest nodes by type, for computing the rank.
  var nodesByType = d3.nest()
      .key(function(d) { return d.type; })
      .sortKeys(d3.ascending)
      .entries(nodes);

  // Duplicate the target-source axis as source-target.
  console.log(nodesByType, "nodes by type");
  // nodesByType.push({key: "source-target", values: nodesByType[2].values});

  nodesByType.push({key: "source-target", values: nodesByType[1].values});

  // Compute the rank for each type, with padding between packages.
  nodesByType.forEach(function(type) {
    var lastName = type.values[0].packageName, count = 0;
    type.values.forEach(function(d, i) {
      if (d.packageName != lastName) lastName = d.packageName, count += 2;
      d.index = count++;
    });
    type.count = count - 1;
  });

  // Set the radius domain.
  radius.domain(d3.extent(nodes, function(d) { return d.index; }));

  // Draw the axes.
  svg.selectAll(".axis")
      .data(nodesByType)
    .enter().append("line")
      .attr("class", "axis")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(" + degrees(angle(d.key)) + ")"; })
      .attr("x1", radius(-2))
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return radius(d.count + 2); });

  // Draw the links.
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "links")
    .selectAll(".link")
      .data(links)
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", link()
      .angle(function(d) { return angle(d.type); })
      .radius(function(d) { return radius(d.node.index); }))
      .on("mouseover", linkMouseover)
      .on("mouseout", mouseout);

  // Draw the nodes. Note that each node can have up to two connectors,
  // representing the source (outgoing) and target (incoming) links.
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "nodes")
    .selectAll(".node")
      .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.packageName); })
    .selectAll("circle")
      .data(function(d) { return d.connectors; })
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(" + degrees(angle(d.type)) + ")"; })
      .attr("cx", function(d) { return radius(d.node.index); })
      .attr("r", 4)
      .on("mouseover", nodeMouseover)
      .on("mouseout", mouseout);

  // Highlight the link and connected nodes on mouseover.
  function linkMouseover(d) {
    svg.selectAll(".link").classed("active", function(p) { return p === d; });
    svg.selectAll(".node circle").classed("active", function(p) { return p === d.source || p === d.target; });
    info.text(d.source.node.name + " → " + d.target.node.name);
  }

  // Highlight the node and connected links on mouseover.
  function nodeMouseover(d) {
    svg.selectAll(".link").classed("active", function(p) { return p.source === d || p.target === d; });
    d3.select(this).classed("active", true);
    info.text(d.node.name);
  }

  // Clear any highlighted nodes or links.
  function mouseout() {
    svg.selectAll(".active").classed("active", false);
    info.text(defaultInfo);
  }
});

// A shape generator for Hive links, based on a source and a target.
// The source and target are defined in polar coordinates (angle and radius).
// Ratio links can also be drawn by using a startRadius and endRadius.
// This class is modeled after d3.svg.chord.
function link() {
  var source = function(d) { return d.source; },
      target = function(d) { return d.target; },
      angle = function(d) { return d.angle; },
      startRadius = function(d) { return d.radius; },
      endRadius = startRadius,
      arcOffset = -Math.PI / 2;

  function link(d, i) {
    var s = node(source, this, d, i),
        t = node(target, this, d, i),
        x;
    if (t.a < s.a) x = t, t = s, s = x;
    if (t.a - s.a > Math.PI) s.a += 2 * Math.PI;
    var a1 = s.a + (t.a - s.a) / 3,
        a2 = t.a - (t.a - s.a) / 3;
    return s.r0 - s.r1 || t.r0 - t.r1
        ? "M" + Math.cos(s.a) * s.r0 + "," + Math.sin(s.a) * s.r0
        + "L" + Math.cos(s.a) * s.r1 + "," + Math.sin(s.a) * s.r1
        + "C" + Math.cos(a1) * s.r1 + "," + Math.sin(a1) * s.r1
        + " " + Math.cos(a2) * t.r1 + "," + Math.sin(a2) * t.r1
        + " " + Math.cos(t.a) * t.r1 + "," + Math.sin(t.a) * t.r1
        + "L" + Math.cos(t.a) * t.r0 + "," + Math.sin(t.a) * t.r0
        + "C" + Math.cos(a2) * t.r0 + "," + Math.sin(a2) * t.r0
        + " " + Math.cos(a1) * s.r0 + "," + Math.sin(a1) * s.r0
        + " " + Math.cos(s.a) * s.r0 + "," + Math.sin(s.a) * s.r0
        : "M" + Math.cos(s.a) * s.r0 + "," + Math.sin(s.a) * s.r0
        + "C" + Math.cos(a1) * s.r1 + "," + Math.sin(a1) * s.r1
        + " " + Math.cos(a2) * t.r1 + "," + Math.sin(a2) * t.r1
        + " " + Math.cos(t.a) * t.r1 + "," + Math.sin(t.a) * t.r1;
  }

  function node(method, thiz, d, i) {
    var node = method.call(thiz, d, i),
        a = +(typeof angle === "function" ? angle.call(thiz, node, i) : angle) + arcOffset,
        r0 = +(typeof startRadius === "function" ? startRadius.call(thiz, node, i) : startRadius),
        r1 = (startRadius === endRadius ? r0 : +(typeof endRadius === "function" ? endRadius.call(thiz, node, i) : endRadius));
    return {r0: r0, r1: r1, a: a};
  }

  link.source = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return source;
    source = _;
    return link;
  };

  link.target = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return target;
    target = _;
    return link;
  };

  link.angle = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return angle;
    angle = _;
    return link;
  };

  link.radius = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return startRadius;
    startRadius = endRadius = _;
    return link;
  };

  link.startRadius = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return startRadius;
    startRadius = _;
    return link;
  };

  link.endRadius = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return endRadius;
    endRadius = _;
    return link;
  };

  return link;
}

function degrees(radians) {
  return radians / Math.PI * 180 - 90;
}
```

Comment: Your fiddle is failing due to a different reason that you've explained.  It looks like the temporary data you've defined in `dataset` in your fiddle doesn't match the structure that you're using in the code you've got inline in your question.  To help though, if you've got a link to a missing node, then you've got two options, either create a node for the missing one and add it to your data, or discard the link and just ignore it.  The appropriate action will probably depend on your use case.

Comment: @BenLyall if you look at the code for Mike Bostocks example, you will see that anything that's in an import array also is a "name". Is that a condition of this type of graph. I think it would obscure results to create or drop. By the way, you use terms "node" and "link": in this case are the imports the links and the "name"s the nodes?

Comment: that's right.  The nodes are the "name"s and the links are the "import"s.  If you want to link something from an import, then you need something to link it to?  What would you propose to link it to if the target doesn't exist?  You can either have a name to link it to (therefore a node) or just not create the link at all.  You need to figure out which is the better way to do it for your use case.

Comment: @BenLyall Thanks, I just got confused by the fact that in Bostock's demo, all the imports themselves import something else (i.e. they are a name), but  there's many classes in programming langauges that don't import anything. I.e. they can be imported but not import anything